# Set EditingArea in HTMLEditor (ajax control)

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, html-editor

I have a HTMLEditor (ajax control).

I want to set the size of EditingArea inside HTMLEditor to look like an A4 size paper.

Can I set the margins on all four sides of the HTMLEditor? If yes, than how to do it?

Is there any other way I can make my HTMlEditor look like an A4 size paper (the way MS Word document pages are shown)?

Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="PILWP.aspx.cs"  Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" tagprefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #form1
        {
            background: #C0C0C0;
            width: 1019px;
            margin-left: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <p style="margin-left: 100px">
            &nbsp;</p>
        <p style="margin-left: 50px">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700" 
                Text="High Court"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;:&nbsp;
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="04">Panaji</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700" 
                Text="Stamp/Regn"></asp:Label>
            :<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Value="50">Register</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="31">Stamp</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">&lt;-- Select --&gt;</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="DropDownList2" ErrorMessage="Select Stamp/Reg" 
                InitialValue="&lt;-- Select --&gt;">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700" Text="Type :"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="DropDownList3" ErrorMessage="Select case type" 
                InitialValue="&lt;-- Select --&gt;">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700" Text="No. :"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="DropDownList3" ErrorMessage="Select case type" 
                InitialValue="&lt;-- Select --&gt;">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </p>
        <p style="margin-left: 50px">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700" Text="Year"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="Enter Year">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="Enter year" 
                ValidationExpression="^\d{4}$">YYYY</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700" 
                Text="Order Date"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="dd/mm/yyyy"></asp:Label>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ErrorMessage="Enter proper format">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ErrorMessage="Enter valid date" 

                ValidationExpression="^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$">dd/mm/yyyy</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </p>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" 
            style="margin-left: 50px" />
        <p style="margin-left: 40px">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
                style="margin: 0 0 0 126px; font-weight: 700" Text="GO" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </p>

    </div>
    <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" AutoFocus="true" Height="400px" 
        style="margin: 0 0 0 100px; text-align: center" Width="800px"  />
    <p>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox 
            ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Height="66px" TextMode="MultiLine" Visible="False" 
            Width="183px"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" 
            Text="pdf preview" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" onclick="Button3_Click" 
            Text="Temp save" />
    </p>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" 
  runat="server" >

   </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField3" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField4" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField5" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField6" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField7" runat="server" />
    <br />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the html markup produced by the editor..you should be  able to set the format..by overriding the css classed used in the control by your own..

Comment: That looks like the markup of what is inside the html editor..the stuff you are editing..not that, do a view source and paste the whole thing...

Comment: Sorry. Please see edited question. Hope this is the thing you need.

Comment: Avoid using spaces for formatting html..I would advice you rewad a good book on html.. Everything is possible with html and css..what I asked for is the html that can be seen when you right click in the browser and do a view source..also just try a single page with only the html editor first..your page has a lot of other elements that are probably messing up your formatting.

Comment: I am looking for Formatting inside HTMLEditor and not the webpage. i want to set margins inside HTMLEditor and not for my webpage containing all the controls.

Comment: Try using padding, in any case the html markup generated should be of most help...the editor area is probably a div and setting padding for this should solve your problem..